# Android plugin for Eclipse (ADT) disappears after SDK 20 upgrading

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

I've just upgraded to the Android SDK rev 20 and since then no way to install the ADT plugin in Eclipse 3.7.2. Although the package (Android DDMS, Android Development Tools) is referenced in the Eclipse installed software, I don't have shown-up any Android project or perspective, at the point that I can't set the SDK path in Windows/Preferences ...
I've also tried to re-install, nada. Accessory: Linux Ubuntu 12.04
Thanks for help!

Comment: happened to me when upgrading ADT 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685, Eclipse 4.2, Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

Answer (score 6):

SDK r20 works only with ADT r20 so you have to update your ADT too.

To update your ADT do the following procedure :

1. In eclipse go : Help -> Install New Software...
2. Now in `Work with` field  type this link `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`
3. Now press enter. You will see some items in list view below. Select all and press next.
4. Now accept the agreement an click next.

This will update your ADT. an you should be able to see it in eclipse

For more information see : [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Comment: Sorry, I've done that from the beginning, the adt is really marked as 20 but the still doesn't show-up in any menu or prespective

Comment: The key of the keys is to delete the content of the directory ~/.eclipse/ then update the ADT as mentioned above! Without emptying that directory nothing happens ...

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problems on Ubuntu 12.10.
I found that this was due to the fact I was using Java 1.5. After upgrading to Java 1.7, the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

What JVM is your default on Ubuntu? ADT requires a JVM that can handle keystores correctly. Using Sun Java 6 is fine.

Besides that, ADT has optional dependencies to some of the Web Service Tools (WST) for the XML editing related features. Maybe you can check whether that is correctly installed?

And if nothing else helps: Eclipse 3.8 and 4.2 have been released 6 days ago, so just using a fresh installation of Eclipse 4.2 together with ADT 20 might be the best choice in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem.

Solved it by going to Help -> Check For Updates.

Deselect everything except the items that specify version 20. Can't remember the exact list by heart.
Then click next and follow instructions.

Should sort out the problem.

Edit:
The most important one is the "Android Development Tools" itself from that list.
The other 3 Android are also important.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the "-vm" option in eclipse.ini with a JDK 1.6 solved the problem for me.

Trying to uninstall/install did not help.